# How to use TextFields.bindAutoCompletion() without a default selection in the suggestions

Tags: java, javafx, autocomplete, controlsfx

The problem here is that there are similar product names so I only want to search for substrings to get a list of products (which is possible).

The method is called like this:

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchTerm, productNames);
```

However the drop down suggestions always highlight the first entry which fires the search for this specific product on enter.

Is there a way to disable this default selection?

Comment: Which version of controlFx are you using ? Does this link related to version 8.40.10 also describe your issue https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/666/autocomplete-selection-issue ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think the version is 8.40.10. I solved the problem by manually creating a searchfield and laying a combobox behind it. Frankly its not a nice one-liner nor is it very fast but it does what it should.